# Subgroups of semidirect product and commuting automorphism

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, semidirect-product

I am not sure if this question actually makes sense, so any corrections/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Let $K$ be a polycyclic group, and let  $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be two automorphisms in $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ such that $\phi_1$ has infinite order and $\phi_1\phi_2$ = $\phi_2\phi_1$. Let $\phi_1'$ be the induced automorphisms on  $K \rtimes_{\phi_2}\mathbb{Z} $, where $\phi_1'$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$ component. Similarly, let $\phi_2'$ be the induced automorphisms on  $K \rtimes_{\phi_1}\mathbb{Z} $, where $\phi_1'$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$ component.

Now suppose
$$ (K \rtimes_{\phi_1} \mathbb{Z})\rtimes_{\phi_2'}\mathbb{Z} \cong (K \rtimes_{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z})\rtimes_{\phi_1'}\mathbb{Z}.  $$

**Question**:Given a subgroup $H$ of $K \rtimes_{\phi_1} \mathbb{Z}$ with finite index $m$, is there a "natural" subgroup $H'$ in $(K \rtimes_{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z})\rtimes_{\phi_1'}\mathbb{Z}$ that contains the subgroup $ \{(h_1,0,h_2) : (h_1,h_2) \in H \}$ with index roughly $m$ (a multiple of "m") ?

I was thinking to take $H' = \{(h_1,n\mathbb{Z},h_2) : (h_1,h_2) \in H \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, unfortunately this subset is not closed in general.

Comment: Your speculation that the question does not make sense is correct, because $\phi_2$ is an automorphism of $K$ and not of $K \rtimes_{\phi_1} {\mathbb Z}$. I cannot see any obvious way to make this meaningful without further assumptions on $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

Comment: Thank you for reading @DerekHolt, I have added some assumptions on the maps

Comment: It still doesn't make sense because in general there is no such induced automorphism $\phi_1'$. I think you would need the $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to commute for this to work.

Comment: Yes indeed they need to commute. Sorry I forgot to put that in the question. Thank you for pointing that out @DerekHolt

Comment: How can $(h_1,0,h_2)$ be an element of $(K \wr Z) \wr Z$?

Comment: Since $(h_1,h_2) \in H$, we have $h_1 \in K$ and $h_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: I think I can construct counterexamples with $\phi_1$ the identity map. I am not sure what the answer is if you assume that $\phi_1$ has infinite order.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would not hold when $\phi_1$ has finite order. I added the assumption that $\phi_1$ has infinite order.